# Using a pre-defined color palette in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how to use a pre-defined color palette in ggplot?

I have a vector of colors I would like to use:

```
rhg_cols <- c("#771C19", "#AA3929", "#E25033", "#F27314", "#F8A31B", 
              "#E2C59F", "#B6C5CC", "#8E9CA3", "#556670", "#000000")
```

But when I try to pass it to nothing happened

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products)), color = rhg_cols) +
  geom_bar()
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You must put `colour = rhg_cols` inside `aes()`. As far as I can tell, you want to apply gradient to bars (in barplot) with factor variable on the abscissa? Then use `fill` - try this instead:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products), fill = factor(phone_partner_products))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = rhg_cols)
```

or try to achieve approximate replica with:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products), fill = phone_partner_products))) +
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#771C19", high = "#000000")
```

Notice that in second case a continuous variable is passed to `fill` aesthetics, therefore `scale_fill_gradient` is passed afterwards. If you pass a `factor` to the `fill` aes, you must stick with `scale_fill_manual(values = rhg_cols)`.

Comment: It should be "high" instead of "hi" on scale_fill_gradient(low = "#771C19", hi = "#000000").

Answer (score 30):

If the colours are a palette, use `scale_colour_manual`:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products), colour = colour_variable)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = rhg_cols)
```

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, however the argument to `scale_colour_manual()` had to be `values=...` to get it to work.

Comment: Just adding from my experience. If your vector is named (i.e. each hex value has a color name), then you'll want to unname the vector before passing it to scale_color_manual, as otherwise it will try to match names to the color variable. So, it'd go like ```scale_colour_manual(values = unname(rhg_cols))```

Answer (score 11):

First add, the colours to your data set:

```
mydata$col <- rhg_cols
```

Then map colour to that column and use `scale_colour_identity`

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products, colour = col))) + 
  geom_bar() + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

Comment: mmm ... the first line has some problem... I have at least 800 row and the colors are only 10

> mydata$col <- rhg_cols
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "col", value = c("#771C19", "#AA3929",  : 
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 865

Comment: and of course the factor(phone_partner_products) returns only 5 elements, so a palette of 10 colors should be enough.

Comment: Oh, it's a palette.  This is why reproducible code is always useful.

Answer (score 10):

Since the colors you want ARE the values in the color aesthetic, what you really want is the `identity` scale, in this case `scale_fill_identity`.

```
 ggplot(mydata, aes(factor(phone_partner_products)), color=rhg_cols) +
   geom_bar() +
   scale_fill_identity())
```

Since you didn't supply data, I'm going to use a slightly different example using your color data:

```
 rhg_cols <- c("#771C19","#AA3929","#E25033","#F27314","#F8A31B",
               "#E2C59F","#B6C5CC","#8E9CA3","#556670","#000000")
 mydata <- sample(rhg_cols, 100, replace = TRUE)
 qplot(mydata, fill = mydata) +
   scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

---

note: I omitted `+ opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=90))` for clarity in the example.