# R - change colors in ggplot2 plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ggplot custom colors palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079264/ggplot-custom-colors-palette)

Hello,

I am using this question - [Making a stacked area plot using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651428/making-a-stacked-area-plot-using-ggplot2) - to make a nice stacked area plot.

The resulting grapg is nice, but I cannot find how to change the colors in `ggplot` graph.

Comment: Take the options given in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079264/ggplot-custom-colors-palette

Comment: Thanks, the "duplicate" comments actually helped a lot. :-)

Comment: there you got me :) I sometimes forget that the "possible  duplicate" comment is automatically generated when I vote to close. Glad I could help twice ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to manual designate the colors you want to use, then use scale_fill_manual.

```
rhg_cols1<- c("#000000","#F8766D","#7CAE00","#00BFC4","#C77CFF" )

ggplot()+geom_bar()+opts()+ scale_fill_manual(values = rhg_cols1)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I got from he duplicate question :)

Also, I need to use `scale_color_manual` so the borders are colored the same way. I will accept you before this question is closed. :)

Comment: Thank Karel, my first picked answer!