# Group similar factors - fills ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the reproducible data that I'm using as an example.

```
Name <- c("Blueberry", "Raspberry", "Celery", "Apples", "Peppers")
Class <- c("Berries", "Berries", "Vegetable", "Fruit", "Vegetable")
Yield <- c(30, 20, 15, 25, 40)
example <- data.frame(Class = Class, Name = Name, Yield = Yield)
```

When plotted with `ggplot2` we get ...

```
ggplot(example, aes(x = Name, y = Yield, fill = Name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image: Graph]

It would be helpful if we could give fills of similar colour to those that have the same class. For example, if Vegetables were shades of blue, Berries were shades of pink, and Fruits were shades of green you could see the yield by class of plants but still visually see the name (which is more important to us)

I feel that I could accomplish this with `scale_fill_hue()` but I can't seem to get it to work

```
ggplot(example, aes(x = Name, y = Yield))+
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Class),stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_hue("Name")
```

[image: Class]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic design in `ggplot` is one scale per `aes`thetic (see @hadley's opinion e.g. [**here**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/lDvsd4yJ0AE)). Thus, work-arounds are necessary in a case like yours. Here is one possibility where `fill` colors are generated outside `ggplot`. I use color palettes provided by package `RColorBrewer`. You can easily check the different palettes [**here**](http://colorbrewer2.org/). `dplyr` functions are used for the actual data massage. The generated colours are then used in `scale_fill_manual`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(RColorBrewer)

# create look-up table with a palette name for each Class
pal_df <- data.frame(Class = c("Berries", "Fruit", "Vegetable"),
                     pal = c("RdPu", "Greens", "Blues"))

# generate one colour palette for each Class
df <- example %>%
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarise(n = n_distinct(Name)) %>%
  left_join(y = pal_df, by = "Class") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(., cols = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 3, name = .$pal))(.$n)))

# add colours to original data
df2 <- example %>%
  arrange(as.integer(as.factor(Class))) %>%
  cbind(select(df, cols)) %>%
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = Name))

# use colours in scale_fill_manual
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = Name, y = Yield, fill = Name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = df2$cols)
```

[image]

A possible extension would be to create separate legends for each 'Class scale'. See e.g. my previous attempts [**here (second example)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568901/multiple-colour-scales-in-one-stacked-bar-plot-using-ggplot/19573826?s=9|0.7705#19573826) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474465/using-different-scales-as-fill-based-on-factor/20479882?s=1|0.0801#20479882).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alpha scale as a quick (albeit not perfect) way to change intensities of colour within a class:

```
library("ggplot2"); theme_set(theme_bw())
library("plyr")
## reorder
example <- mutate(example,
               Name=factor(Name,levels=Name))
example <- ddply(example,"Class",transform,n=seq_along(Name))
g0 <- ggplot(example, aes(x = Name, y = Yield))
g0 + geom_bar(aes(fill = Class,alpha=factor(n)),stat = "identity")+
    scale_alpha_discrete(guide=FALSE,range=c(0.5,1))
```