# How to use its own palette with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, palette

I have defined a palette with `colorRampPalette` to be used for each plot. How can set this palette by default with ggplot2 ?

I have no idea how to do that and could not find the answer.

MWE :

```
df <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3], y = runif(3), fill = LETTERS[1:3])
mypalette <- colorRampPalette(colors = c("white", "blue"))
```

Now how to use the palette itself and not the hack:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_col(aes(fill = fill)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette(3))
```

And more generally speaking, is there something like `theme(palette = mypalette)` so has to have always it own palette by default ?

Comment: Not my downvote but, could you please provide a small example of data and the ggplot statement you would like to use it in.

Comment: Looks like a [Previous SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079264/using-a-pre-defined-color-palette-in-ggplot) used the same `scale_fill_manual` solution that you came up with

Comment: I had a look at this post too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the following strategy sometimes useful:

```
scale_fill_discrete <- function(...) 
  scale_fill_manual(..., values=palette())

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_col(aes(fill = fill))
```

[image]

```
palette(c("#738290", "#A1B5D8",  "#C2D8B9"))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_col(aes(fill = fill))
```

[image]